# Proof of chain rule using little-oh; Hunter

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, chain-rule

The following is a proof of the chain rule from John K. Hunter's [lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html). It uses the little-oh concept, i.e. a function $f(h)$ is little-oh of $h$ if $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)/h=0$. Come to think of it, the proof below answer's [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557937/642262). Anyway, I have only one question about the proof at the very end.

The proof uses the following proposition:

> **Proposition 8.11.** Suppose that $f: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$ if and only if there exists a constant $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and a function $r: (a-c,b-c)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(c+h)=f(c)+Ah+r(h), \quad \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0.$$ In that case, $A=f'(c)$.

> **Theorem 8.21** (Chain rule)**.** Let $f: A\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g: B\to\mathbb{R}$ where $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f(A)\subset B$ and suppose that $c$ is an interior point of $A$ and $f(c)$ is an interior point of $B$. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(c)$, then $g\circ f: A\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c$ and $$(g\circ f)'(c)=g'(f(c))f'(c).$$

In the proof below, I think there is a typo in the tagged equation (it should be = instead of <).

> **Proof.** Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$, there is a function $r(h)$ such that
> $$
> f(c+h)=f(c)+f^{\prime}(c) h+r(h), \quad \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{r(h)}{h}=0,
> $$
> and since $g$ is differentiable at $f(c)$, there is a function $s(k)$ such that
> $$
> g(f(c)+k)=g(f(c))+g^{\prime}(f(c)) k+s(k), \quad \lim _{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{s(k)}{k}=0 .
> $$
> It follows that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> (g \circ f)(c+h) & =g\left(f(c)+f^{\prime}(c) h+r(h)\right) \\
> & =g(f(c))+g^{\prime}(f(c)) \cdot\left(f^{\prime}(c) h+r(h)\right)+s\left(f^{\prime}(c) h+r(h)\right) \\
> & =g(f(c))+g^{\prime}(f(c)) f^{\prime}(c) \cdot h+t(h)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where
> $$
> t(h)=g^{\prime}(f(c)) \cdot r(h)+s(\phi(h)), \quad \phi(h)=f^{\prime}(c) h+r(h) .
> $$
> Since $r(h) / h \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$, we have
> $$
> \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{t(h)}{h}=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{s(\phi(h))}{h} .
> $$
> We claim that this limit exists and is zero, and then it follows from Proposition 8.11 that $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $c$ with
> $$
> (g \circ f)^{\prime}(c)=g^{\prime}(f(c)) f^{\prime}(c) .
> $$
> To prove the claim, we use the facts that
> $$
> \frac{\phi(h)}{h} \rightarrow f^{\prime}(c) \quad \text { as } h \rightarrow 0, \quad \frac{s(k)}{k} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { as } k \rightarrow 0 .
> $$
> Roughly speaking, we have $\phi(h) \sim f^{\prime}(c) h$ when $h$ is small and therefore
> $$
> \frac{s(\phi(h))}{h} \sim \frac{s\left(f^{\prime}(c) h\right)}{h} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text { as } h \rightarrow 0 .
> $$
> In detail, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We want to show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
> $$
> \left|\frac{s(\phi(h))}{h}\right|<\epsilon \quad \text { if } 0<|h|<\delta .
> $$
> First, choose $\delta_{1}>0$ such that
> $$
> \left|\frac{r(h)}{h}\right|<\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1 \quad \text { if } 0<|h|<\delta_{1}
> $$
> If $0<|h|<\delta_{1}$, then
> $$
> \begin{align}
> |\phi(h)| & \leq\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right||h|+|r(h)| \\
> & <\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right||h|+\left(\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1\right)|h| \\
> & <\left(2\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1\right)|h| \tag{*}.
> \end{align}
> $$
> Next, choose $\eta>0$ so that
> $$
> \left|\frac{s(k)}{k}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1} \quad \text { if } 0<|k|<\eta
> $$
> (We include a "1" in the denominator on the right-hand side to avoid a division by zero if $f^{\prime}(c)=0$.) Finally, define $\delta_{2}>0$ by
> $$
> \delta_{2}=\frac{\eta}{2\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1}
> $$
> and let $\delta=\min \left(\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}\right)>0$.
>
> If $0<|h|<\delta$ and $\phi(h) \neq 0$, then $0<|\phi(h)|<\eta$, so
> $$
> |s(\phi(h))| \leq \frac{\epsilon|\phi(h)|}{2\left|f^{\prime}(c)\right|+1}<\epsilon|h| .
> $$
> If $\phi(h)=0$, then $s(\phi(h))=0$, so the inequality holds in that case also. This proves that
> $$
> \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{s(\phi(h))}{h}=0 .
> $$

If $\phi(h)= 0$, then $s(\phi(h))=0$. Why? I have a far-fetched idea. The author states that we have $ \frac{s\left(f^{\prime}(c) h\right)}{h} \rightarrow 0 $ as $h \rightarrow 0$. If $o(h)$ denotes all functions that approach zero faster than $h$ as $h\to 0$, and if $s(h)\in o(h)$, then by limit substitution also $s(ah)\in o(h)$, where $a$ is a constant. However, what happens when $a=f'(c)=0$, as presumably can be the case. Then does $ \frac{s\left(f^{\prime}(c) h\right)}{h} \rightarrow 0 $ when $h\to 0$? Only if $s(0)=0$. I don't know, maybe there's a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes that seems to be a careless typo in the text you flagged.
2. I believe that the conditions imposed on $r(h)$  in Proposition 8.11  ought to have stated  explicitly that $r(h)$ is continuous as $h\to 0$. Then it is evident that $r(0)$ must be zero. The same applies to the expression $s(k)$.
3. There is a much cleaner conceptual approach to the definition of the derivative that was developed by Caratheodory about 100 years ago (based upon the simpler concept of continuity) . See e.g [Question about Caratheodory's approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303322/from-carath%C3%A9odory-derivative-definition-to-the-derivative-of-sinx) and the reference to Bernstein' notes cited therein. The Chain Rule can be proved in one line using this approach.

A nice expository article explores this in detail:

*The Derivative á la Carathéodory*
Stephen Kuhn
**The American Mathematical Monthly**, Vol. 98, No. 1 (Jan., 1991), pp. 40-44 (5 pages)

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324035

Quoting from its introduction:

> But there is another, less well known, characterization of the
> derivative which appears in the last textbook [2] written by
> Constantin Caratheodory (1873-1950). This formulation is not only
> elegant but useful on both theoretical and pedagogical grounds. The
> proofs of many important theorems concerning differentiability become
> significantly easier and, in the process, some of the less
> enlightening details are rightly submerged. Caratheodory's formulation
> also gives us a much clearer view of the fact that continuity is
> essential for differentiability; indeed, the definition itself
> contains the necessary continuity. This formulation, which shifts the
> details from the theory of limits to the theory of continuous
> functions, requires that our students develop a clearer understanding
> of continuity than is typical and it demands that we reevaluate this
> understanding and continually reinforce it. We believe that
> Caratheodory's insight deserves to be better known and we hope that
> the present article will help in that effort.

4. The multi-variable extension of Caratheodory's approach is explained in this article:

*On the Differentiability of Functions of Several Variable*s
Michael W. Botsko, Richard A. Gosser
**The American Mathematical Monthly**, Vol. 92, No. 9 (Nov., 1985), pp. 663-665 (3 pages)

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323717

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Interesting. $r(h)$ in Proposition 8.11 is nothing more than the Peano form of the remainder, right? Nowhere have I seen it stated being continuous, e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), but maybe that's just obvious?

Comment: By solving for $r(h)= f(c+h) -f(c)- f'(c) h$ one can deduce that $r(h)$ is continuous. I  should have pointed that out earlier.